# adding html in values of a form

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have tried to pass html as value with POST method for each post. 
The variable/custom field "tech_specs" contains a table in html:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style>.....</td>
            <td style>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style>....</td>
            <td>....</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The form gets

```
echo "<form method='post' action='.../comparison-page/' >";

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

           $my_id= get_the_ID();      
             $tech_spec = get_post_meta($my_id, 'tech_specs');
             echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"comparison[".$i_meta."]\" value=\"".$tech_spec."\" />";

     $i_meta++;
        endwhile;

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
            echo "</form>";
```

As seen in the picture, [html to value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scl0Q.jpg) in the checkboxes I get value="Array". The problem, I am facing is "Array to string conversion".
How can I transfer the values (html table for each value) so I can parse them in another page through the table comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you can add an print_r to see what in the variable $tech_spec,

```
$tech_spec = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tech_specs');
print_r($tech_spec);
//will return something like these :
//Array ( [key_1] => Array ( [0] => value_1 ), [key_2] => Array ( [0] => value_2 ) )
```

Extract what you want from the array $tech_spec.

In your echo you can put something like these :

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"comparison[".$i_meta."]\" value=\"".$tech_spec['key_1']."\" />";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't understand the structure of this array. One question can i have something like this in my input tag: echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"comparison[".$i_meta."]\" value=\"".$tech_spec[' value_". $i." ']."\" />";

Comment: Yes accepted it. I was asking if i  can use another index eg 'value_". $i ." ' in the tech_spec array:    `value=\"".$tech_spec[' value_**" . $i. "** ']."\"`

Comment: If 'value_". $i ." ' existe as $tech_spec array key YES, try print_r($tech_spec); or var_dump($tech_spec) to see the content

Comment: The content is what i was expecting but when i try to get the value with this: `foreach ($tech_spec as $tech_row){
   $tech_value = $tech_row[0];  }` it appears  <1